# How do i handle multiple deployment environments with minimal effort in kubernetes?

Tags: docker, web-applications, kubernetes

I'm a newbie here, and i am in the process of preparing my development and production environment for a webapp Microservices architecture. I have injected environment variables through my deployment files in order to control the environment by which the app will be running. For example a Microservice running in development mode will work with development databases. So my question is, what do you think is the best practice to control multiple environment deployments. Should i have multiple deployment files, one for each environment for the same Microservice? Or is there a better practice?
Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Typically you want that applications running on the `dev` environment don't interfere with applications running on the `production` environment. Using Kubernetes, you can get this kind of isolation [using different namespaces](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/namespaces/) for different environments. That way, objects on the `production` namespace are different from objects on the `dev` namespace. Another, more expensive approach would be to use different k8s clusters for different environments.

Having this setup, you would deploy your application in the namespace for the specific environment where you want to deploy to, creating the `Deployment` object on that namespace. This `Deployment` would make use of a `ConfigMap` object containing your application environment variables. The variables inside the `ConfigMap` will be different on each namespace/environment.
That way, your `Deployment` object is the same across different environments, which let's you be more confident that what you are testing on `dev` is the same that you will use on `production`. The `Deployment` object is the same, but it uses different variables to run.

Using [the example Pod from the documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: dapi-test-pod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: test-container
      image: k8s.gcr.io/busybox
      command: [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "env" ]
      env:
        # Define the environment variable
        - name: SPECIAL_LEVEL_KEY
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              # The ConfigMap containing the value you want to assign to SPECIAL_LEVEL_KEY
              name: special-config
              # Specify the key associated with the value
              key: special.how
  restartPolicy: Never
```

Saving that content into `pod.yaml`, we can create it in our namespaces with `kubectl -n my-namespace-development create pod.yaml`, and `kubectl -n my-namespace-production create pod.yaml`.

This Pod would use a ConfigMap called `special-config`. This configmap can be created like `kubectl -n my-namespace-production create configmap special-config --from-literal=special.how=very` in production, and `kubectl -n my-namespace-development create configmap special-config --from-literal=special.how=very-dev`.

As you can see, the configmap content is different on each namespace. So the Pod created on the namespace called `my-namespace-production` will use the value `very`, but the pod created on the namespace `my-namespace-development` will use the value `very-dev`.

Comment: how do i control the namespace through config map? i mean how to i make the namespace param in deployment file get its value from configmap?
thanks

Comment: You just reference the configmap by name from your deployment file. So the deployment will use the values of the configmap that lives on the same namespace that the deployment object.

Comment: Added example to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @fiunchinho answer. Kubernetes documentation provides 3 ways of managing deployments, services, etc:

1. **Imperative commands** - a user operates directly on live objects of a cluster, for example

   ```
   kubectl create deployment <name-of-deployment> --image nginx
   kubectl edit deployment <name-of-deployment>
   ```

   For more information go through this [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/object-management-kubectl/imperative-command/)
2. **Imperative object configuration** - the kubectl command specifies the operation, optional flags and at least one file name. The file specified must contain a full definition of the object in YAML or JSON format, for example

   ```
   kubectl create -f nginx.yaml
   kubectl replace -f nginx.yaml
   kubectl delete -f nginx.yaml
   ```

   For more information go through this [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/object-management-kubectl/imperative-config/)
3. **Declarative object configuration** - a user operates on object configuration files stored locally, however the user does not define the operations to be taken on the files. Create, update, and delete operations are automatically detected per-object by `kubectl`, for example

   ```
   kubectl apply -f nginx.yaml
   kubectl apply -f configs/
   ```

   For more information go through this [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/object-management-kubectl/declarative-config/)